# Outer border of selection in GIMP

Tags: gimp

How I make outer border of selection in GIMP ?
I tried stroke selection, but the half of the border  covers the selection area and half is out  of the selected area.  I want the border to be completeley out of the selected area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in 2.8 and 2.10:

#### Method #1

- Select>To path
- Select>Invert
- Edit>Stroke path (give twice the required width, since the selection will discard the inner half of the outline)

In general, stroking a path gives a cleaner result than stroking a selection anyway.

#### Method #2

If you make the border on another layer, you could also:

- Edit>Stroke selection
- [delete]

This will remove the inner part of the outline (but using the method above is cleaner).

Comment: Method #2 works for me :)  thank you very much!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted, then.

Answer (score 0):

In Gimp 2.10.12. we can tell the selection border area to continue outside of the selection as shown here for the selection border menu:

[image]

If we then apply a fill (red 50% opacity) to that selection it will be applied only outside of the previously selected green area:

[image] [image]